# What does a method with return type void return exactly?

Tags: c#

I know it may sound pretty stupid, but I am starting and I really don't know. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Technically nothing.  C Language is very precious in instruction syntax so the compiler can catch all errors.  The void is needed so the compiler doesn't produce false error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it does not return anything at all